# Generating all the increasing subsequences

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

Given an array of integers, how can we generate all the increasing subsequnces  of length of 4  ?

Example: given this list

```
l = [1, 2, 4, 5, 3, 6]
```

The answer should be :

```
[1, 2, 3, 6]
[1, 2, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 4, 6]
[1, 2, 5, 6]
[1, 4, 5, 6]
[2, 4, 5, 6]
```

I generated this algorithm using python :

```
def verif(x,temp):
    work=[]
    for k in temp:
        if len(k)<4 :
            if k[-1] < x :
                work.append(k+[x])
    return work+[[x]]

temp=[[1]]
for i in range(1,len(l)):
    print(i)
    zeta=verif(l[i],temp)
    for i in zeta:
        if len(i)==4 :
            print(i)
    temp+=zeta
    zeta=[]
```

I want to improve my approach , which is very slow for bigger lists unfortunately , is there another algortihm which works faster ?

Comment: Is your approach slow, or are there just too many sequences?

Comment: For a list of 500 integers , it becomes very slow

Comment: $\binom{500}{4} = 2573031125$. That's two and a half billion.

Comment: I didn't use combinations

Comment: That’s the number of sequences you’re trying to generate.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm to generate all increasing sequences of length $4$ of the numbers $1,\ldots,n$:

```
for d in {4,...,n}:
  for c in {3,...,d-1}:
    for b in {2,...,c-1}:
      for a in {1,...,b-1}:
        output a,b,c,d
```

Comment: And what if the sequnces is not sorted ? , this an o(n^4) complexity time , what if we had a 1000 integers list ?

Comment: There are $\Theta(n^4)$ sequences. You cannot generate all of them in less than $n^4$ time.

Comment: My approach is faster i think in  $ O {(n^2)} $ , but i want a linear approach

Comment: It is impossible to generate $\Theta(n^4)$ tuples in time $O(n^2)$. Think about it – can you generate 10000 tuples in 100 steps?